# XML XPath convert YYYMMDD date into month name?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am working on importing data from an XML file. This is the node path to the date node that is formatted as `YYYYMMDD`.

```
//Product/Manufacturer/CreationDate/Date
```

I need to take the date and return the month name - i.e. 20200206 returns February. I've tried using the `month-from-dateTime()` and `month-from-date()` functions but neither have worked. My guess is that I need to format the date differently before being able to use these functions to convert the date into month name.

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="*[date]">
        <xsl:value-of 
            select="date/
                    format-date(
                        xs:date(
                            concat(
                                substring(.,1,4),'-',
                                substring(.,5,2),'-',
                                substring(.,7,2)
                            )
                        ),
                        '[MNn]'
                    )"
            separator="&#xA;"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<root>
    <date>20200206</date>
    <date>20201010</date>
    <date>20201206</date>
    <date>20200404</date>
    <date>20200606</date>
</root>
```

Output:

```
February
October
December
April
June
```

**Do note**: [`format-date()` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-format-date)

Comment: Or use  `replace(//Date,'(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})','$1-$2-$3')` instead of `concat` and `substring`